# Detect closed loop with same value in 2D array

Tags: arrays, graph, depth-first-search

Given a 2D array consisting of elements of different values, how to detect if there is a loop consisting of same value? A loop is defined to have two or more adjacent element with same value and has the same starting and end point.

```
l = [
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "G", "G", "G", "B"],
    ["B", "G", "B", "G", "B"],
    ["B", "G", "G", "G", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
]
```

This is array has two loops of "B" and "G", respectively.

Comment: I assume the entire loop consists of the same value (either B or G) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the center and expand outward. At worst it will O(n). 
I think its more than sufficient hint to solve.